# How to add new table to the database using sql workbench

Tags: mysql-workbench

I was creating MySQL database to add medicine.I created a table and I need to add one more tabe.After creating it I tried to query the database from the sql workbench.But it donot show the table but it is present in the EER Model.How can I solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modeling is just the task of abstractly designing your schema and its objects (e.g. tables, views etc.). It does not actually create these objects. For this you have to forward engineer your model to a server (see Database menu). Once done you can use the Synchronization feature to update either model or server (or both) with any changes made.

But keep in mind this is only for the objects, not for any data.